# active jmx in tomcat and spring app

Tags: jmx

i'm using tomcat 5.5, with a spring app, and i having memory leak problems.
so i'm trying to connect jmx in my spring app to monitoring the app, and try to find what is causing the memory leak, but i can't yet.

i add the Mbeanexporter in my aplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
      <property name="beans">
          <map>
              <entry key="bean:name=catalogFacadeTarget1" value-ref="catalogFacadeTarget"/>
          </map>
      </property>
</bean>
```

and in the catalina.sh

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.managment.jmxremote.host=localhost 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

i run jconsole, but there no have any of my bean.

i need some direction here, thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set `lazy-init = false` for your MBeanExporter to get picked up. Like so:

`<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
 ...
</bean>`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial on google, maybe it could help you:

http://blog.markshead.com/1129/connecting-visual-vm-to-tomcat-7/